How to Typeset This Word with Cjhebrew?
I have been trying to typeset this word in a document with cjhebrew:

But I have not been able to get the "double dots" underneath the third letter from the left.
What I have so far, is this:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge
\centering\cjhebrew{`rAh}
\end{document}

which gives

Can someone tell me how to modify the MWE so that its output matches the Hebrew word I am trying to typeset?

I have no idea about Hebrew, but by the magic of looking in the manual I got this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\cjhebrew{`erAh}
\end{document}



The tsere is e in this package, so the simplest fix is:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge
\centering\cjhebrew{`erAh}
\end{document}

However, this package is obsolete.

+1 It is hard to distinguish between the two answers, so I checked the one which came first.
